# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "RNFBApp"

Tags: firebase, react-native, cocoapods, analytics

I am trying to install firebase analytics in my react native application. For that I am following the link for documentation

https://enappd.com/blog/firebase-analytics-in-react-native-app/101/

My iOS deployment target is 9.0 in the xcode and also 9.0 in the Pods file. But when I tried to install the two plugins

```
yarn add @react-native-firebase/analytics
yarn add @react-native-firebase/app
```

I tried to do

```
cd ios && pod install
```

I got the error:

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "RNFBApp":
  In Podfile:
    RNFBApp (from `../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app`)

Specs satisfying the `RNFBApp (from `../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

Then I googled this error none of them are working solution for me. I tried

```
rm Podfile.lock
pod install --repo-update
```

Still the same issue

Then I updated the deployment target to 10.0. Then it was installed successfully. But now I am not able to build the application for iOS because it is giving error

```
Typedef redefinition with different types ('uint8_t' (aka 'unsigned char') vs 'enum clockid_t')
```

This was happening in the Flipper library of the react native. Then I reverted back my code and now my deployment target is again 9.0 and I am stuck.

Please anyone can guide me to solve this issue.

Comment: Can you share your entire `podfile`? Just to have a look. Also it might be the min version issue which RNFirebase don't support. I can't find evidence to proof the statement, but you can always ask in their github discussion. Nevertheless, try convience your team about letting go iOS 9. I would say super duper less user is on iOS 9, perhaps supporting iOS 10 as minimum will be better.

Comment: @TommyLeong I did it initially, I changed the sdk version in the deployment target of xcode as well as in the pod file. I have written about it. The error is not allowing to build the application in xcode. Getting the error as stated in the last section 

```
Typedef redefinition.... 
```
Issue is happening for Flipper plugin of react native

Comment: Are you on `XCode 12.5`?

Comment: I have used both 11.6 and 12.4. Results is same. I did not use 12.5